# How do I edit the hosts file on Windows 7 when the instructions don't work?

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions, uac, notepad

All instructions I find say to run Notepad as Administrator and open the hosts file from there. Sounds logical, but when I try to save the hosts file I get the following error in a dialog box:

```
hosts
This file is set to read-only.
Try again with a different name.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Ramhound That dupe is close, but it's about Access Denied, where as this one is about Read-only.  Splitting hairs to some, but different answers to fix it. (If someone had suggested read-only on the other I'd have probably agreed with the dupe ;) ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure you remove the Read-Only attribute from the HOSTS file.

[image]

Some Anti-malware packages like to force it to be read-only, so you may have to disable your anti-malware before you'll be able to do that.

Perhaps check out these related SU questions:

- [How can I modify my hosts file? It is read-only and cannot be modified even as Adminstrator.](https://superuser.com/questions/124888/how-can-i-modify-my-hosts-file-it-is-read-only-and-cannot-be-modified-even-as-a)
- [Windows 7 HOSTS files keeps reverting it's permission back to READ-ONLY](https://superuser.com/questions/788946/windows-7-hosts-files-keeps-reverting-its-permission-back-to-read-only)

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit the file you will either need to open it as Administrator or modify the file, save it to your Documents folder then overwrite the current file (You will be prompted to overwrite as Administrator).

Answer (score 0):

after edited I always saved it somewhere else， then copy it to that folder，when the system ask you for administrator privilege， you click ok to overwrite original file.